# Loading a new SKScene for the first time lags

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm making a game a game in Xcode 6 using SpriteKit and swift. When I transfer from my starting scene to my "Play Game Scene" for the first time it takes 5 to 10 seconds. I have tried going to this scene from various other scenes and I still get this same lag. I thought it was the code at first, but this problem only recently started, but also, after I go to this scene the first time (and it lags), then I transfer to a different scene (the game over scene), when I go back to it, it no longer lags. It only lags the first time I transfer to this scene. I have also tried making a new project and copying and pasting all of the code from all of the scenes to a new scenes. If there is a simple explanation for this, please help. I don't understand why it would only lag the first time I go to the scene. If there isn't a simple answer, I suppose I will have to read through all of the code...AGAIN. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

-Callum

Comment: Make sure you are reusing texture references rather than allocating the same textures each time. Use atlases and load directly from the atlas (I.e don't make  sprite kit search for your atlas). Try preloading some of your atlases in the background. If you have too many assets and can't get around the delay, then show a loading screen and initialize your scene on the background thread. This will let you display an animated loading screen on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 months later I came back to the project and found out it was because I use a non-specific font name. The font I used was "Felt Marker", but it should have been "Felt Market-Thin". If you don't give an exact font name, it takes a few seconds to figure out it was not specific so it goes to the default.

Here is a list of all the IOS fonts with their specific types:

http://iosfonts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your scene is probably loading textures or other files into the memory the first time you start the scene, and then these remain in the memory for the rest of the session. If you have texture atlases that you are loading in the scene, you can pre-load these using:

```
SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases(textureAtlases: [AnyObject]!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (() -> Void)!)
```